# "statemenet with no effect" error in eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse

I have this line of code,

```
newCust.idNumber == ID;
```

the value of ID is of type string and is already assigned, newCust is the name of my struct, and idNumber is a string in my struct, I want to assign the value of ID to the struct's ID Number, any idead why this line of code is a "statement with no effect" please. I am using eclipse, and I am a beginner in C programming

Comment: As this Q is tagged as C, to copy *C string* you have to make use of `strcpy`, `strncpy` or `strdup`, assignment may not serve your purpose

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `==` compares two values, and discards the result of that comparison. Although expression-statements like that are perfectly legal in C, they are highly unusual, and often serve as an indicator of you typing something incorrectly. That's why the compiler warns you about it.

**EDIT:**

> I tried the = also, and i get this error then, incompatible types when assigning to type `char[60]` from type `char *`

You can't assign strings like that: you need to use `strcpy`, like this:

```
strcpy(newCust.idNumber, ID);
```

Make sure that `newCust.idNumber` is long enough to fit the `ID` together with its null terminator, i.e. given that `newCust.idNumber` is `char[60]`, the value of the `ID` must be 59 characters or less.

Comment: I tried the = also, and i get this error then, incompatible types when assigning to type 'char[60]' from type 'char *'

Answer (score 1):

Because you're doing a comparison and throwing away the result.  You probably wanted

```
newCust.idNumber = ID;
```

Note the single equal sign.

Comment: I tried the = also, and i get this error then, incompatible types when assigning to type 'char[60]' from type 'char *'

Comment: another.anon.coward answered this in his/her comment on the question actually.  Since this is C code, you want to use one of the standard library's string copy functions to actually perform the copy.  Otherwise, it's going to just try copying the underlying pointer which isn't what you want in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

`==` checks for equality, it is not an assignment operator.

And since you do not check for the return code of the check, Eclipse (rightly) yells at you.

Comment: I tried the = also, and i get this error then, incompatible types when assigning to type 'char[60]' from type 'char *'